# Arc GIS 10.1 - How to sort Layers ascending at TOC in "List by drawing order"

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I have some 100 features in my ArcMap Project. I choose at TOC the View mode "List by drawing order". 
How can I sort this list ascending or by name alphbetical?
Under the options field, is nothing like this.
The drawing order should be ascending by name.
Or how can I sort them on other way?

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a script using [MoveLayer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/movelayer.htm) and a temporary Group Layer to get this to work. First create a new group layer anywhere in your TOC (it doesn't matter what it's called, it will be deleted at the end). This only works based on the assumption that this temporary group layer is the only one in the mxd. Of course, this can be bypassed by giving your temporary layer a constant name (such as "TempGroup"), and changing the script to use that group layer specifically for the sorting.

```py
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0] # Assuming one data frame
group_lyr = [lyr for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd) if lyr.isGroupLayer][0] # The temp group layer should be the only one
lyr_names = sorted(lyr.name for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd) if lyr.isFeatureLayer)

for name in lyr_names:
    arcpy.mapping.MoveLayer(df, group_lyr, arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, name)[0], "BEFORE")

arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, group_lyr)
```

Gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/cindygis/35aa1108225212bc88d7). I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop.

Comment: add those lines in the end of Cindy Williams code: `mxd.save()` `del mxd`

Comment: The abovementioned change is only required if the script is called programmatically on an existing mxd. The answer was written with the assumption that it will be run in the Python window in ArcMap.

Comment: thanks Cidny, but i i run in external python file.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to sort the *List By Drawing Order* TOC (without programming).

But it is possible to sort the *List By Visibility* TOC and the *Listing by selection* TOC: Go to the *option* button on the TOC. On the Preferences tab chose whether to sort layers by the order they are drawn or alphabetically by layer name (*Sort layers by*).

Comment: Thanks. But I know the other sorting ways. Esri help describe that ways. But not my case what I need. How can I program it? I found something with PLTS but found nothing in that way. Thanks again for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it

Sorting the table of contents in alphabetical order, please find detail in:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0106000001qt000000

Comment: This looks like it is possible only when you have this extension, and not plain ArcMap.